# Upgrade to Yosemite has negative impact on objectForKey mp3 image

Tags: mp3, nsdictionary, osx-yosemite

Just updated to Yosemite and Xcode 6.0.01 and this code no longer works:

```
- (NSImage *)songImage {
    if (!_songImage) {
        AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:self.fileURL];
        for (AVMetadataItem *metadataItem in asset.commonMetadata) {
            if ([metadataItem.commonKey isEqualToString:@"artwork"]){
                NSDictionary *imageDataDictionary =
                    (NSDictionary *)metadataItem.value;
                NSData *imageData = [imageDataDictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
                _songImage =[[NSImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
            }
        }
    }
    if (!_songImage) {
        return Nil;
    }

    return _songImage;
}
```

I'm not sure if the process was replaced or removed but I now get a message:

```
2014-10-17 14:36:23.756 FSC Music[3317:122917] -[__NSCFData objectForKey:]: unrecognized
    selector sent to instance 0x600000241cb0 2014-10-17 14:36:23.764 
FSC Music[3317:122917] -[__NSCFData objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
     0x600000241cb0
```

need to research a solution, but wanted to ask if anyone else has come across this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed to the following code to get it working again.

```
 -(NSImage *)songImage {

    if (!_songImage) {
        AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:self.fileURL];
        NSArray *metadata = [asset commonMetadata];
        for ( AVMetadataItem *item in metadata ) {
            if ([item.commonKey isEqualToString:@"artwork"]){

                NSData *thePix = (NSData *)item.value;

                _songImage =[[NSImage alloc] initWithData:thePix];
             }
        }
    }
    if (!_songImage) {
        return Nil;
    }

    return _songImage;
}
```

Comment: Tested new code on Maverick OSX 10.9.5 SDK 6.0.1 (6A317), and it fails:

2014-10-20 07:49:57.694 FSC-adap[62467:303] -[__NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x610000670c40
2014-10-20 07:49:57.695 FSC-adap[62467:303] -[__NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x610000670c40
2014-10-20 07:49:57.698 FSC-adap[62467:303] (
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff96a4125c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     

I assume I'll now have to test versions before deciding which path to take.